# ASP.NET Web Application for POS ON ICEbrowser® SDK - broswer and IBM 4690 OS - Operating Systems

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am running in to an issue. I have to develop .NET WEB application (MVC or WEB Forms  , MVC is preferred), it will be used by users at POS  (Point of sale) terminal which had Operating System -- IBM's 4690 concurrent OS and Browser  ICEbrowser® SDK 6.1.2

I am in dilemma if we can run successfully .NET Web Application on Browser ICEbrowser® SDK 6.1.2 in an IBM's 4690 concurrent OS machine.

Environement of Web Server is Windows Server 200R2, Users Environment has Operating System - IBM's 4690 and Browser -- ICEbrowser® SDK 6.1.2

Can we run .NET Web App (MVC or Web Forms) on IBM'S 4690 OS with  IceBrowser SDK browser  ??

Current production with same environment is using a Web Application developed in JAVA (used Servlets).

Please help me... this is going to be a Show Stopper for the whole Project.

Comment: we aren't here to make product decisions for you.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am not looking for PRODUCT DECISION Mr.White, All I was trying is whether .NET Web Apps works with that particular browser and OS... as this forum has wide range of developer community thought I would get some help/inputs... Unnecessarily Don't rate down the question sir...

Comment: The ASP.Net will run on the Web server (IIS) and not on the client. The only thing you have to worry is if the client browser can render the HTML response and can execute javascripts.

Comment: @pinoy_ISF thanks for your response.. so as the server technology/code is independent of client all I should worry is-- it brings down to -- need to check what versions of HTML/CSS/JavaScript/JQUERY will be supported by that browser ? Am I correct ??

Comment: Thank You @pinoy_ISF, that's all what I was looking for... I thought the same but though to have some clarification from the experts like you... thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to the complete documentation on ICE browser.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=219&context=SW880&context=HW196&q1=ICEsoft&uid=pos1R1004644&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en

Answer (score 1):

As other users have answered your question... Let me give you some generics... IBM 4690 was initially built from FlexOS which was branchedout from DOS and the latest IBM 4690 runs on a Linux kernel and I have witnessed a Firefox browser to be able to run successfully.

For more details: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=pos1R1004839

Comment: thanks for providing the ibm link, I will go through it.